# React-Native Stack navigator go back to previous screen with same initialRouteName

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a React Native app and am using react navigation's stacknavigator, and here is my scenario:

- I have a component **A** as a stacknavigator that contains screen **B** (and others).
- Clicking on a button in A navigate to B
- Clicking on a button in B navigate to B (this time with new data)
- Clicking on default back button of second B navigate to A. **And that's my issue, since I want to go back to first B**
  Check my stacknavigator config, and correct me if I missed an extra config, Thank you.

```js
<AppStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HOME"
    screenOptions={stackStyle}>
    <AppStack.Screen
        name="HOME"
        component={A}
    />
    <AppStack.Screen
        name="B"
        component={B}
    />
....
```

Within B:

```js
const {navigation} = this.props;
navigation.navigate('B', {new data for second B});
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that first B trigger second B from a webview

Comment: Can I see what you are doing when you click on button B. Are you trying to do something like navigation.navigate('B') from the B screen ?

Comment: Exactely @HichamELBSI

Comment: In my opinion, you should not do this. You should re-render the screen with a state update or just the component you need for this screen.

Comment: Ok so what type of issue calling from same screen is it? it is a good practice to not do?

Comment: navigation.replace('screenA')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should deal with the state of your components to rerender. Anyway, if you just need to navigate to the same page and keep the go back, you can replace :

```js
navigation.navigate('B', { ... })
```

by :

```js
navigation.push('B', { ... })
```

When you use `push`, you create a new route so when you will go back from this new route, it will navigate to the previous one. `navigate` will try to go to an existing route so in your case: the route B already exists actually.

Comment: That makes sense, will give it a try and get back to you. Btw still confused with 'you should not do this.' because in my use case if i changed the state the content of the web view will change but the user can't go back to the first content of the webview. Did you get my point?

Comment: TBH it depends on your use case. Navigating from B to B can be useful for example if you want to navigate between user profiles or between two details page. But I was talking about a classic use case that you navigate from an empty B page to a filled data B page.

Comment: Thanks, I could come with a solution that combines both (state and push). Again I have a special use case as I mentioned I should update webview content in same B screen.